# Поменять кодировку в POST запросе?

Tags: android, кодировка, post, okhttp

Подключил OKhttp+Retrofit,делаю POST запросы,. Все,вроде ок, но приходят в кодировке `utf-8`, а надо `charset=iso-8859-2`
Пробовал

```
.addHeader("Content-Type","charset=iso-8859-2")
```

не помогает

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submitbutton"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все проще. Кодировку можно задать, когда формируем запрос,только не ошибиться в синтаксисе.

```
 RequestBody  contact_name= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; charset=iso-8859-2"), "łżąęóńż");
```

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию используется UTF-8. 
Могу предложить добавить Interceptor к Okhttp клиенту

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor { chain ->
                        val request = chain.request()
                        val response = chain.proceed(request)
                        val rawJson = response.body()?.bytes()?.let {
                            String(it, Charset.forName("iso-8859-2"))
                        }?:""
                        response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()?.contentType(), rawJson)).build()
                    }
...
.build()
```

Попробуйте так